# Postgresql union of 2 tables with identical structure is very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning

I have 2 tables (call them tableA and tableB) with the same structures, 4 columns (date,character varying, character varying, value), with a PK on the first 3 columns.

table A is partitioned by range on date (20 partitions), contains 13M rows.
table B is not partitioned, and contains a couple hundred rows.

I have defined table_view as the simple union of selects of the two tables.

Now `select count(*) from tableA` takes a few ms.
`select count(*) from tableB` takes a few ms.
However `select count(*) from table_view` takes 10 seconds. Performance of other queries on the union is also poor although not as bad (say 3-5x as slow as if performed on tableA only.

I'm quite puzzled by this. Is there anything obviously wrong that I should correct?

Comment: Is the view using a `union` or a `union all`? `union` does a `distinct` which might be why your query is slow.

Comment: Please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement and the DDL for the tables and indexes involved. All in plain text, as an update of your original question.

Comment: They are not of identical structure, one is partitioned one is not. Without the information requested by @FrankHeikens there is not really much that can be provided in the way of an answer. Be sure and include your partitioning design.

Comment: @amphetamachine you figured it out. I was doing ```UNION``` and not ```UNION ALL``` (didn't know ```UNION``` was doing ```DISTINCT```), thanks a lot for posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the view using a `union` or a `union all`? `union` (without `all`) does an implicit `distinct` which might be why your query is slow.

Comment: That was my mistake, thank you for identifying.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure your question was marked as answered, rather than just have my comment above be the answer.

Comment: Yes, understood. Thanks again.